# Can i use a DDR3 4GB ram in DDR3 PC3-12800 motherboard?

Tags: memory

Is a DDR3 4GB 1333mhz memory module ram compatible with my DDR3 PC3-12800 motherboard.?I really need to upgrade my ram.
My motherboard is HP and Intel Pentium G2100T CPU.So can i upgrade my ram?

Comment: What motherboard? What module? What CPU?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/380678/ddr3-memory-is-pc3-10666-compatible-with-pc3-12800

Comment: @ali786 That one appears related, but not quite the same. Your linked question asks whether PC3-10666/10600 DIMMs can be replaced with PC3-12800 DIMMs. This asks whether (most likely) PC3-10666/10600 is compatible with a motherboard that is designed to support PC3-12800. They are similar, but from different angles.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - Sounds identical to me.

Answer (score 1):

[DDR3 PC3-12800 corresponds to 1600 MT/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#JEDEC_standard_modules) ([megatransfers per second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_%28computing%29)). There is no standardized 1333 MHz DDR3 type at least according to Wikipedia, so you are probably referring to 1333 MT/s, otherwise known as PC3-10600.

Generally speaking, slower RAM of the otherwise correct type is compatible with a motherboard capable of supporting faster RAM, but you won't be getting the full potential performance out of the RAM since the slowest component forms the bottleneck. When that is the motherboard rather than the RAM, the motherboard sets the limit at the lower level mutually supported by both.

Hence, while there is no way to be absolutely certain without knowing a lot more details, chances are **quite good** that it will work fine, just not as fast as it possibly would on a motherboard capable of utilizing the full RAM bandwidth. The effect in practice of this is however likely to be limited, and overshadowed by the fact that by having more RAM available you avoid the need to swap (which even in the case of swapping to [a SSD is *orders of magnitude* slower than RAM](https://superuser.com/a/686384/53590), depending on which exact metric you compare).